# C# Winforms Event is adding _1 at the end of everything

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2022

My project became corrupt today and since fixing i have noticed that at the end of events like button click its adding `_1` at the end of everything

for example

```
private void createNewUserToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

where as it should obviously be

```
private void createNewUserToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

I have no idea what has happened but its causing me to repeat a lot of work. I have not duplicated controls or anything like that so i am very confused

Does anyone have any ideas? Please this is over 2 years of work and its looking like its knackered

Comment: You don't use Git, I assume?

Comment: I do use GIT but stupidly i didn't commit my changes up so i would loose a fair bit of work if i were to restore

Comment: The only way I can reproduce this is when you already have a `createNewUserToolStripMenuItem_Click` method, then use the designer to create a new method.

Comment: You get "_1" added when there is a naming conflict. When there isn't a conflicting other method anymore now then just use the "refactor" option in your editor to change the name of the methods. And if you don't know what happened(and maybe what also happened) you might want to stash your changes first before starting cleanup.

Comment: Seems that the controls had disappeared and recreated - No idea why because they are in the designer of the form but not on the actual interface its also only impacting 1 form notothers

Comment: Consider registering event handlers in the constructor with `+=` instead of in the designer

Comment: The designer lost the fact that the control was wired up and when you double click it it sees that there is already a method with that name so it adds one. All you need to do is select that control, go to the Events listing in the Properties pane, find that event, and then change the listed handler using the dropdown back to the original method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Idle_Mind this worked -

The designer lost the fact that the control was wired up and when you double click it it sees that there is already a method with that name so it adds one. All you need to do is select that control, go to the Events listing in the Properties pane, find that event, and then change the listed handler using the dropdown back to the original method. –